# Parsing Data, Excel to Python

Tags: python, excel, parsing

So I have a excel(.csv) data file that looks like:

```
Frequency   Frequency error  
0.00575678  17
0.315       2
0.003536329 13
0.00481     1
0.004040379 4
```

where the second column is the error in the first data column e.g. the value of the first entry is 0.00575678 +/- 0.0000000017 and the second is 0.315 +/- 0.002. So using python is there a way to parse the data using Python so that I can get two data arrays, the 1st being frequency and the 2nd the frequency error. Where the first entry in the 2nd array is in the format of 0.0000000017. If this was a small data file I'd do it manually but it has a few thousand entries so its not really an option. Thanks

Comment: you should edit you question. But I think the good way is to parse each line separately. use string.split('+/-') then convert each element to float()

Comment: How does `17` in the first line translate to `0.0000000017` but `2` in the second line is `0.002`?  What controls the scale?

Comment: It's just the way the datafile

Comment: There's different decimal places. The error is taken as that number say '17' from the last digit

Comment: Then why isn't the 2 mapped to 0.0002?

Comment: Because the error its associated with (0.315) only goes upto the 3rd decimal place.

Comment: Then 17 should become 0.000000017, no?

Comment: Well yes but thats the question, I want to find a way to have the second column as an array in python to the correct decimal place

Comment: So which is it supposed to be, 0.0000000017 or 0.000000017?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not the fastest, but looks close.

```
sample = """\
0.00575678,17
0.315,2
0.003536329,13
0.00481,1
0.004040379,4"""

for line in sample.splitlines():
    value,errordigits = line.split(',')
    error = ''.join(c if c in '0.' else '0' for c in value)[:-1]
    error += errordigits
    print "%s,%s" % (value,error)
```

prints:

```
0.00575678,0.000000017
0.315,0.002
0.003536329,0.0000000013
0.00481,0.00001
0.004040379,0.000000004
```

Comment: Oh that looks great, I'll let you know how it goes

Comment: Is there a way to get the excel columns in that format: 1st column, 2nd column?

Comment: At the moment its just in a normal excel file with two separate columns

Comment: Save your excel spreadsheet as a CSV and it will give you that format.

Comment: Wouldn't that be saved as two different arrays when loading in the columns. And it would give all the frequency values and then all the error values rather than frequency value then its associated error, then the next frequency and that values error etc

Comment: I guess you could try it and find out.

Comment: It gives me an error: "for line in sample.splitlines():
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'splitlines"

Comment: I used `sample.splitlines()` in my sample code just to illustrate iterating over a list of strings (which is created by calling `splitlines()` on a single multiline string). You will have to adapt my example code to use the appropriate methods and data types depending on how you choose to input the data from your source file to this program. Troubleshooting that process is really beyond the scope of this comment thread - your original question has been answered, after all. There are probably a number of existing questions on SO to help you with this next step.

Answer (score 0):

i found pandas useful to get data from a csv.

```
f = pandas.read_csv("YOURFILE.csv");
dfw = pandas.DataFrame(data = df, columns=['COLUMNNAME1','COLUMNNAME2'])
y = df.COLUMNNAME1.values
x = df.COLUMNNAME2.values
```

Comment: Would this make say the value '17' come out as 0.0000000017 and '2' come out as 0.002 ?